# Document is not getting downloaded from url in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, download

I have written below method to download a pdf file from URL getting from Firebase. Code is running smoothly but file is not being downloaded.

```
Future<void> _downloadFile() async {
    setState(() {
      _downloading = true;
    });
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(widget.products['pdfURL']));
    final documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final file = File('${documentDirectory.path}/my_file.pdf');
    await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);

    setState(() {
      _downloading = false;
      _localFilePath = file.path;
      print(_localFilePath);
    });
  }
```

When I am printing the file path getting below result.

```
I/flutter (15500): /data/user/0/com.deworb.notes/app_flutter/my_file.pdf
```